# All list items up to, and including, the first repeated item

Tags: j

Consider:

```
x =. 0 1 2 3 4 1 3 4 99
v =. [ {.~ (>: @ i.&1 @ (#@~. = #\))
v x   NB. => 0 1 2 3 4 1
```

The behavior is correct.  But as you can see, `v` is shamefully verbose.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: It seems your `v` is not working for all cases (a typo?). `0(=i.1:)#.</\(=/~)x` gives you the index of the first repeated item. I would try, perhaps, starting from `x #~ }:1, *./\+/"1</\(=/~.)x` and see what I could do.

Comment: By the way, as much as I like this type of questions, I don't think it fits stackoverflow; it seems too open ended. Maybe reword to something more concrete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the monad `~:` ([nub sieve](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d222.htm)):

```
   v =: {.~ 1 + 0 i.~ ~:

   x =: 0 1 2 3 4 1 3 4 99

   v x
0 1 2 3 4 1
```

Code review:

- Outside code-golf contexts, don't use `#\` in place of `i.@#`. It's too cutesy, hard to maintain, and won't be recognized by the special-code optimizer.
- Don't assign to the names `x`, `y`, `u`, `v`, `m`, or `n` (except in special circumstances, and always locally in an explicit context).

Comment: As usual, just what the doctor ordered.  Thanks Dan.

Comment: @Jonah NP. My recommendation is that next time you have code that works but you worry about aesthetics, ask on [codereview.se] rather than SO.  BTW, I keep meaning to get back to you on your 2-arg do-while question but haven't had the time.

Comment: Dan, yeah this really does belong on code review.  Tbh, I mostly posted it here because I knew you'd see it :)  Wasn't sure if you used CR.

Comment: @Jonah You can always ping me. I'm pretty responsive when I'm online.

Comment: @Jonah Keep in mind that Code Review has different standards for their questions. Make sure you read their [help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to avoid getting your question closed. The question as it currently stands would likely be closed as "unclear what you're asking" since it's lacking context. Afar from that, you're both welcome to visit CR anytime :-)

Comment: @Mast I have lots of experience on CR.  There is no reason a question like this should be closed other than one of the overactive hall monitors deciding to nitpick one of their inane rules (which is always possible -- I won't argue with you there).  Anyone with any experience in J would know exactly what was being asked here.  Context is irrelevant, other than possibly stating if I cared about maximum performance or not.

Comment: @Jonah Context is relevant if the rules state it's relevant. There's not a large userbase for [tag:j] on Code Review either. [Context usually improves the chances of a good review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) as well. Sure, go ahead and risk it, it's your question after all. I just thought I'd warn and safe you the frustration if your question doesn't get answered or even gets closed.

Comment: [NuVoc](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/SpecialCombinations#Miscellaneous_Functions) claims that ``#\`` and `#\.` are in fact recognized by the optimizer. In general, I do believe `>:@i.@#` is better since its readable (why is that form not recognized?).

Comment: @miles Good eye. My suspicion is `#\ `, however unidiomatic, is easier to put into an optimization table than the longer `i.@#`. But I still won't endorse it. Except for code golf: there, it's a gem.

Comment: @DanBron, i'd appreciate any thoughts on:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169813/ascii-triangle-in-j

Comment: @DanBron, requesting your expertise once again here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171007/golfing-n-choose-k-in-j